# Many-to-Many Relationship with 3 FKs

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, data-modeling

I'm about to create a Java application (with Spring Boot and React in the front) that simulates a bank and, to store the data, i have chose PostgreSQL as my DBMS. This project is only for study purposes.

The app will allow the user to:

- create an account;
- do some banking operations (like simulate deposit and transfer to another account);
- verify its own statement;
- check the transaction history.

I'm doing all the application from scratch and I was modeling the data, changing from logical to physical data model, when I've encountered this problem (i'm new in the Stack Overflow, so i'm not allowed to post an image directly):

[image: Logical Data Modeling]

The **Transaction** entity is referring two accounts, because in the real world a transaction is made from one account (idSourceAccount) to another (idDestinationAccount). And like in the real world too, **one account can perform many transactions; and one transaction involve two accounts (source/destination) obligatorily.**

The main problem is that, in a N:M relationship we need to create an intermediate table to break the N:M relationship. In this case, **Account_Transaction** would have two FKs from Account, what is not breaking the N:M properly, as show the image:

[image: Physical Data Modeling (incomplete)]

Am I modeling wrong this problem? What can i do to solve this?

PS: I've searched through the internet and not found a model that makes sens with reality (like Transaction entity with only one idAccount).

UPDATE: Is this a possible approach?
[image: Alternative Logical Model]

Comment: Your first model is right. The `Transaction` table models this M:N relationship between the table `Account` and itself.

Comment: @TheImpaler right, but between `Transaction` and `Account` shouldn't have an intermediate table `Transaction_Account?`

Comment: I don't think so. The first model is a bit misleading since the table `Transaction` has two FKs, but the image only shows "one link" between `Transaction` and `Account`. A correct image should have two links, one per FK.

Comment: @TheImpaler i've updated the question with a new image from Logical Model. Do you mean this? Two links between `Account` and `Transaction`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The updated diagram depicts both relationships maybe named "Debited from Account" and "Credited to Account".